# Postgresql - Window Function Aggregate

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I'm attempting to find the number of new users per month by product type. However, I continue to receive an error requesting `cnt` to be used in an aggregate function.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) AS month
FROM (SELECT users.date,
             COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY product_type) AS cnt FROM users) AS u
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a very strange construct.  Here is a method that doesn't use window functions:

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as  yyyymm, product_id, count(*)
from (select distinct on (u.userid) u.*
      from users u
      order by u.userid, u.date
     ) u
group by date_trunc('month', date), product_id
order by yyyymm, product_id;
```